# Computing a threshold function

Tags: decision-problem, probability-theory, probabilistic-algorithms

Let $f$ be any function from $\{0, 1\}^{n}$ to $\{-1, 1\}$. For a given $f$, let us define another function $g_f$ as
\begin{equation}
g_f(x) = \sum_{x \in \{0, 1\}^{n}} f(x).
\end{equation}

Let us be given black box access to an unknown $f$ (you can assume the function to be chosen uniformly at random from the set of all possible functions from $\{0, 1\}^{n}$ to $\{-1, 1\}$, if it helps.)

We want to find out whether
\begin{equation}
g_f(x) \geq \alpha,
\end{equation}
for a fixed threshold $-2^{n} \leq \alpha \leq 2^{n}$.

Here is our algorithm that produces an estimate $\hat e$.

1. Sample $k$ $n$-bit binary strings $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k$ uniformly at random, where $k$ is polynomially bounded.
2. Evaluate $f(x_1), f(x_2), \ldots, f(x_k)$.
3. Let
   \begin{equation}
   \hat e = 2^{n}\left(\frac{f(x_1)+ f(x_2) + \ldots + f(x_k)}{k}\right).
   \end{equation}
4. If $\hat e \geq \alpha$, say that $g_f(x) \geq \alpha$. Else, say otherwise.

I am trying to compute the following probabilities.

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Pr}[g_{f}(x) \geq \alpha ~~|~~ \hat e \geq \alpha]~~\text{and}~~\mathrm{Pr}[g_{f}(x) \leq \alpha ~~|~~ \hat e \leq \alpha].
\end{equation}

My idea was to use a Chernoff bound type argument, but I do not know how to handle the conditional. My intuition is that as $n$ increases, the number of paths exponentially increase, and the two probabilities get smaller and smaller --- we cannot possibly infer too well about any global property by looking at only a small fraction of the paths.

Comment: Use Bayes’ formula.

Comment: While using Bayes' theorem, I don't see how to put an upper/lower bound on $\mathrm{Pr}[\hat e \geq \alpha ~~ | ~~ g_{f}(x) \geq \alpha ]$ and $\mathrm{Pr}[\hat e \geq \alpha]$, the end goal being to upper and lower bound $\mathrm{Pr}[g_{f}(x) \geq \alpha ~~|~~ \hat e \geq \alpha]$.

Comment: Try using Chernoff.

Comment: Chernoff only gives me an upper bound. The problem is, to compute an upper bound on the conditional, I also need a lower bound on $\mathrm{Pr}[\hat e \geq \alpha]$ (as this term is in the denominator).

Comment: You need a prior on $f$. Depending on the prior, each of your probabilities could be 0, 1, or anything in between.

Comment: What if go with a uniform prior (that is, $f$ is chosen uniformly at random from the set of all possible functions mapping $n$ bit strings to $1$ and $-1$)?

Comment: In the particular case of binomial random variables, there are lower bonds on the tail. You can look them up.